# Separate key (legend) for colors and markers

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot with several types of objects (each read from a separate file). I'm plotting the same several functions for all of them, all on the same graph (same X-axis).

I set the markers (`pt`) explicitly for each, and the color (`lc`), so the same object has the same marker, but the same function has the same color. As an example we have 2 files, one for each object (`|` is just to separate the files here):

```
0 0 0   |   0 1 1
1 1 2   |   1 1 2
```

Let's call the left file **A**, the right **B**. Column 1 in each file is the `x` axis, column 2 is `using 1:2`, and column 3 is `using 1:3`. So using the above files in an interactive session:

```
gnuplot> plot "A" using 1:2 with lp pt 1 lc 'black'
gnuplot> replot "A" using 1:3 with lp pt 1 lc 'red'
gnuplot> replot "B" using 1:2 with lp pt 2 lc 'black'
gnuplot> replot "B" using 1:3 with lp pt 2 lc 'red'
```

we get:

[image: theplot]

Is it possible to have the key separated, so A/B appear next to their respective marker, and the function name ("using...") appears next to a line (or anything) with the appropriate color?

Right now by omitting titles (`notitle` in the plot command) I can get one or the other, though I would have to settle on some uniform arbitrary marker/color (depending on what I chose to set as key). Can I:

1. Get two keys somehow? - Preferably setting the missing attribute (color or marker) to something not in the plot.
2. If not, can I customize a manual legend somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not fully sure what you want to achieve, nevertheless as for the splitting of the key, I don't think that Gnuplot has some "out-of-the-box" feature for this. However, you could (ab)use `multiplot` to achieve this effect. The idea is basically to generate two overlapping plots - one `with points` and one `with lines` - and to position the keys independently:

```
set terminal pngcairo rounded font ",16"
set output 'fig.png'

$A << EOD
0   0   0
1   1   2
EOD
$B << EOD
0   1   1
1   1   2
EOD

set multiplot

set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror

eps = 0.1
set lmargin at screen eps
set rmargin at screen 1 - eps/2
set bmargin at screen eps
set tmargin at screen 1 - eps/2

#common key settings
set key left top Left reverse spacing 1.5

set key at screen 0.1,screen 1-eps
plot \
    $A u 1:2 with p ps 1.5 pt 1 lc 'black' t 'A', \
    $A u 1:3 with p ps 1.5 pt 1 lc 'red' t 'A' , \
    $B u 1:2 with p ps 1.5 pt 2 lc 'black' t 'B', \
    $B u 1:3 with p ps 1.5 pt 2 lc 'red' t 'B'

unset border; unset xtics; unset ytics

set key at screen 0.3,screen 1-eps
plot \
    $A u 1:2 with l lc 'black' t 'using 1:2', \
    $A u 1:3 with l lc 'red' t 'using 1:3', \
    $B u 1:2 with l lc 'black' t '', \
    $B u 1:3 with l lc 'red' t ''
```

This would give you:
[image]

Comment: I was already doing that fake plot hack, but the multi-plot makes it perfect (separating the keys). Only one annoyance - I can't play around in`qt` terminal and export to `pdf`, since once you go multiplot you can't change terminals, but it's good enough. I was also using a lot of `replot`'s, but you have to use `plot` in this method.

Comment: As for what I'm trying to achieve, I have 5 different object classes, and 4 functions I want on the same plot. I wanted the viewer to be able to follow an object separately and a function separately. There are many more datapoints, so the visual is important.